# Fail to install lxml in custom directory on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: python, linux, lxml

I can install lxml via `pip install lxml`, but I can't install it in desired directory via `pip install lxml -t /path/to/dir` as mentioned in this [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html). Does my command needs more options or lxml can't be installed in other directory?

The following are messages outputed after installation failed:

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
Successfully installed lxml-3.6.0
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 395, in run
    for item in os.listdir(lib_dir):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpzHnGVW/lib/python/'
```

Comment: What is the output when you do `pip install lxml`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Sorry, I forgot to install necessary libraries to build lxml. I have updated my question now, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: It seems like an [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3056) of pip.